# Explain total memory reported by node on AKS

Tags: kubernetes, memory, azure-aks, units-of-measurement

I'm trying to understand what the **memory capacity** means when running: `kubectl describe node <mynode>`
Snippet of the Result:

```
status:
  capacity:
    cpu: '16'
    ephemeral-storage: 129886128Ki
    hugepages-1Gi: '0'
    hugepages-2Mi: '0'
    memory: 65861880Ki
    pods: '110'
  allocatable:
    cpu: 15820m
    ephemeral-storage: '119703055367'
    hugepages-1Gi: '0'
    hugepages-2Mi: '0'
    memory: 61361400Ki
    pods: '110'
```

I know the memory under *allocatable* is a calculation based on the information we can find on [resource reservations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-clusters-workloads#resource-reservations%5D). My question is not about this.

Why is the capacity 65861880Ki while this is a VM with 64G of memory. I assume 64GiB and not GB but even then 65861880Ki is lower than 64GiB (67108864KiB) which is a difference of 1246984KiB (=1,19GiB or 1.3GB).

What am I missing?